# If pattern is present in path then execute

Tags: linux, grep, command

Our repositories directory path = **/srv/git/repositories/group_name/subgroup_name/project.git**

We would like to  execute a script If group name starts **'es-'** right after **repositories** in the path name. I have tried below command to find pattern

Can anyone please help me to get the output?

Example :

```
if echo $pwd | grep -q -e "/ * / * /repositories/es-* /* /* " ;
```

Thank you all

Comment: damn! someone came along and downvoted this entire post.... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if echo "$PWD" | grep -q 'repositories/es-'; then
    execute_script
fi
```

or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
if grep -q 'repositories/es-' <<< "$PWD"; then
    execute_script
fi
```

or

```
grep -q 'repositories/es-' <<< "$PWD" && execute_script
```

Comment: @ Gilles Quenot, Can we put If condition for grep like, 'repositories/es-' or 'repositories/et-' or repositories/dt- ....etc

Comment: `grep -Eq 'repositories/(es|et|dt)-'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do these using pure `bash` built-ins,

```
#!/bin/bash

pat='repositories/es-'
if [[ "$PWD" =~ $pat ]]; then
   # Execute my script
fi
```